# Find strings in strings

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string:

`here "is 'a' \"string\" that" does contain a 'lot of "weird"' stuff "i" to 'find'`

I want to extract `is 'a' \"string\" that`, `lot of "weird"`, `i` and `find`.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: http://ad.hominem.org/log/2005/05/quoted_strings.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This negative lookbehind based regex should work for you:

```
/(["']).*?(?<!\\)\1/g
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/X3etmgKFNH

**Regex without support of lookbehind e.g. Javascript**

```
/(['"])(?:\1|.*?[^\\]\1)/g
```

#### Live Demo: http://www.rubular.com/r/SQyEYIPS4l

Comment: Looks smart. Any chance to make it work with JavaScript, where look-behind is not supported? (Should have mentioned that)

Answer (score 2):

You can try with this pattern:

```
/"((?:[^"\\]+|\\"|\\)*)"|'((?:[^'\\]+|\\'|\\)*)'/g
```

Content inside double quote is in group 1,
content inside single quote is in group 2.

Notice: this solution is not totally waterproof for escaped quotes because if `\"`, that can detect the pattern above, is preceded by another `\`, then the `\\` is seen as a literal `\` and the quote is no more escaped!

To avoid this trap, you can check cases when you have an odd number of backslashes replacing `\\"` by `(?:\\{2})*\\"`, then the first pattern will look like this:

```
/"((?:[^"\\]+|(?:\\{2})*\\"|\\)*)"|'((?:[^'\\]+|(?:\\{2})*\\'|\\)*)'/g
```

Comment: Works with the example however when any other character is escaped like: `here "is \'a\' \"string\" that"` it won't.